# Working with Lightning Design System framework, locally

Tags: lightning-design-system

I'd like to design the front end of my app using the Lightning Design System framework before I hook it up to the backend of my salesforce org. I downloaded the resources from the [Light Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com) site. These are the resources I have connected to my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<head>
   <title>Project Name</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css">
</head>
```

It appears that some resources are not showing up when implement the code, such as SVGs. Also, the modal isn't closing when I set the `aria-hidden="true"`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Suggest you include a couple of the elements that don't work in your question. Setting the default namespace to [http://www.w3.org/2000/svg](http://www.w3.org/2000/svg) doesn't make much sense if most of your elements are HTML e.g. namespace [http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml).

Comment: While SFDC's docs about Lightning Design System in Trailhead include that `<html xmlns=` tag, I would probably suggest that you follow an example like this one for [using the design system with standalone HTML markup hosted by Heroku](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/heroku/). (Even if you are not planning to use Heroku as your web host in the end.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the path to the asset for the SVG icon. The code you copy and paste from the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com) site for the modal is like so

```
<div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <div class="slds-modal__container">
    <div class="slds-modal__header">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
        </svg>
```

Since my index.html file was on the same level as the assets folder, I needed to include a `.` in my file path

```
<div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <div class="slds-modal__container">
    <div class="slds-modal__header">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--large">
          <use xlink:href="./assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
        </svg>
```

The modal not closing involves the `aria-hidden="true"` and making sure the CSS tags `slds-fade-in-open` and `slds-backdrop--open` are removed from the modal code. And of course using JavaScript to add/remove the classes when the appropriate buttons are clicked.